# Train Mobilnet V2 with transfer learning in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, models, training-data, transfer-learning

Folks,

How can I do transfer/domain learning with mobilenet v2? I use the mobilnet v1 training code to train mobilenet v1, but is there written code to train v2 either in the models repository, or in the tensorflow repository?

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Asher Mancinelli, actually, this code does exactly what I need:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/hub/r0.1/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim/nets/mobilenet) has the mobilenet v2 tfslim modules, as well as the checkpoint files to restore weights already trained by the tensorflow people. You can use [this](https://kwotsin.github.io/tech/2017/02/11/transfer-learning.html) example to retrain the model, or you can take a simpler approach with [this](https://kylewbanks.com/blog/tutorial-transfer-learning-retraining-inception-mobilenet-with-tensorflow-and-docker) tutorial. If you're looking for portability, might want to look at TFLite, which would allow you to take any tensorflow model and easily optimize it for mobile with the build tools at tensorflow head: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/python/tools.

Best of luck

Comment: check this code out. It does the training already: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/hub/r0.1/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py